# Word unscrambler

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I'm working with some of the corpus materials from NLPP. I'm trying to improve my unscrambling score in the code... at the moment I'm hitting 91.250%.

The point of the exercise is to alter the represent_word function to improve the score.
The function consumes a word a string, and this word is either scrambled or unscrambled. The function produces a "representation" of the word, which is a list containing the following information:

- word length
- number of vowels
- number of consonants
- first and last letter of the word (these are always unscrambled)
- a tuple of the most commonly used words from the corpus, who's characters are also members of the given word input.

I have also tried analysing anagrams of prefixes and suffixes, but they don't contribute anything to the score in the shadow of the most common words with common characters tuple.

I'm not sure why I can't improve the score. I've even tried increasing dictionary size by importing words from another corpus.

The only section that can be altered here is the represent_word function and the definitions just above it. However, I'm including the entire source incase it might yield some insightful information to someones.

```
    import nltk
    import re

    def word_counts(corpus, wordcounts = {}):
    """ Function that counts all the words in the corpus."""
    for word in corpus:
        wordcounts.setdefault(word.lower(), 0)
        wordcounts[word.lower()] += 1
    return wordcounts

JA_list = filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), map(lambda x:x.lower(), 
                        nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('austen-persuasion.txt')))
JA_freqdist=nltk.FreqDist(JA_list)
JA_toplist=sorted(JA_freqdist.items(),key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:0]
JA_topwords=[]
for i in JA_toplist:
    JA_topwords.append(i[0])

PP_list = filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(),map(lambda x:x.lower(), 
                            open("Pride and Prejudice.txt").read().split()))
PP_freqdist=nltk.FreqDist(PP_list)
PP_toplist=sorted(PP_freqdist.items(),key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:7]
PP_topwords=[]
for i in PP_toplist:
    PP_topwords.append(i[0])

uniquewords=[]
for i in JA_topwords:
    if i not in PP_topwords:
        uniquewords.append(i)
    else:
        continue
uniquewords.extend(PP_topwords)

def represent_word(word):
    def common_word(word):
        dictionary= uniquewords 
        findings=[]
        for string in dictionary:
            if all((letter in word) for letter in string):
                findings.append(string)
            else:
                False
        if not findings:
            return None
        else:
            return tuple(findings)      
    vowels = list("aeiouy") 
    consonants = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvexz") 
    number_of_consonants = sum(word.count(i) for i in consonants)
    number_of_vowels = sum(word.count(i) for i in vowels)
    split_word=list(word)
    common_words=common_word(word)
    return tuple([split_word[0],split_word[-1], len(split_word),number_of_consonants, number_of_vowels, common_words])





def create_mapping(words, mapping = {}):
    """ Returns a mapping of representations of words to the most common word for that representation. """
    for word in words:
        representation = represent_word(word)
        mapping.setdefault(representation, ("", 0))
        if mapping[representation][1] < words[word]:
            mapping[representation] = (word, words[word])
    return mapping

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a mapping of representations of the words in Persuasian by Jane Austen to use as a corpus
    words = JA_freqdist
    mapping = create_mapping(words)

    # Load the words in the scrambled file
    with open("Pdrie and Puicejdre.txt") as scrambled_file:
        scrambled_lines = [line.split() for line in scrambled_file if len(line.strip()) > 0 ]
        scrambled_words = [word.lower() for line in scrambled_lines for word in line]

    # Descramble the words using the best mapping 
    descrambled_words = []
    for scrambled_word in scrambled_words:
        representation = represent_word(scrambled_word)
        if representation in mapping:
            descrambled_word = mapping[representation][0]
        else:
            descrambled_word = scrambled_word
        descrambled_words.append(descrambled_word)

    # Load the original words
    with open("Pride and Prejudice.txt") as original_file:
        original_lines = [line.split() for line in original_file if len(line.strip()) > 0 ]
        original_words = [word.lower() for line in original_lines for word in line]

    # Make a list of word pairs from descrambled_words and original words
    word_pairs = zip(descrambled_words, original_words)
    # See if the words are the same
    judgements = [descrambled_word == original_word for (descrambled_word, original_word) in word_pairs]
    # Print the results
    print "Correct: {0:.3%}".format(float(judgements.count(True))/len(judgements))
```

Comment: @Charles, I'm horrified. You removed "thanks" but didn't notice the new tag `[ntlk]` vs `[nltk]` :-).7

Comment: @Ben, yikes!  Yeah, not sure how I missed that.  I probably did it on my phone and spaced on what I was actually doing.

Comment: i don't understand - in the code above the first and last letters are *not* always unscrambled (afaict).  yet you say that they are.  also, have you tried just sorting the letters?  i don't see how anything can beat that, since you are using all the info available (anagram preserves everything but order, so sorting removes the one thing that an anagram also removes).